# Can I give my react-select menu bootstrap classes?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have given the select component some bootstrap classes, but I have noticed that the menu isn't the same width as the component see this image:

[image]

This is how my select component is build up:

```
 <Select 
            className="col-sm-4 offset-sm-2 filter"
            classNamePrefix="select"
            placeholder="Options"
            options={options}
            styles={customStyles} 
          />
```

I would like to make use of the bootstrap classes in my menu so it will be responsive the same way. I would expect `width:100%` to be the same width as the component but this isn't the case.

```
  const customStyles = {

    control: provided => ({
      ...provided,
      height: '55px',
      borderRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      boxShadow: 'none'
    }),
    group: provided => ({
      ...provided,
      paddingTop: 0,
      paddingBottom: 0
    }),
    groupHeading: provided => ({
      ...provided,
      display: 'none'
    }),
    menu: provided => ({
      ...provided,
      marginTop: '-1px',
      borderRadius: '0px',
    }),
    menuList: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      padding: '0px',
      overflow: 'hidden',
    }),
    option: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      borderBottom: '1px solid #b0b0b0',
      color: state.isSelected ? 'white' : '#000000',
      background: state.isSelected ? '#e3155c' : 'white',
      fontFamily: 'Qanelas-Regular',
      fontSize: '16px',
      padding: '15px',
      ':hover': {
        ...provided[':active'],
        backgroundColor: '#e3155c',
        color: 'white'
      },
    }),
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added `width: 'calc(100% - 30px)'` on menu, I forgot about the gutter width which comes with Bootstrap.